# Change size of UIView inside UIViewController dynamically with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I'm popping this custom UIViewController

[image]

and I set the number of lines on the Summary label to 0.

In the implementation file of the view i did:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.lblSummary.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width - 40.f;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

This should automatically resize the summary label (and accordingly it's view), but it doesn't. It still cut's off the label at the end of its first line.

[image]

I tried the same code in a UITableViewCell and it worked there. How come it doesn't work here? And how can I fix it?

Comment: I think it miss something related to intrinsicContentSize .You can find some explanation in this article http://devetc.org/code/2014/07/07/auto-layout-and-views-that-wrap.html

Comment: Are you sure your `UILabel` is set to be multi-line?

Comment: @IanMacDonald yes, in Interface builder i set the number of lines to 0. i also added it in viewdidload `[self.lblSummary setNumberOfLines:0];`